# Frozen Synapse on LAN, direct connect?

Tags: frozen-synapse

I've heard that Frozen Synapse is having a lot of central server problems that can make it hard to play online.

Since the game is essentially PBEM, is it possible to play over a LAN, simply via external email client, or some way that doesn't require a working central server?

Comment: I know they've already begun improving the servers, and it's already one of their top priorities.  I've also heard they plan to combine all of the different servers into one sometime down the road (hopefully sooner rather than later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and this is intentional. It has been mentioned on game's IRC channel, that they are not going to support LAN game in order to make pirating the game more difficult.

Comment: well I hope they get their server problem sorted out soon!

Comment: let's hope this doesn't backfire into frustrated players supporting cracked version due to LAN _support_, those guys wouldn't deserve it

Comment: Another problem will be if players would like to play it in 2020 when maybe it will be no longer economical for the company to run the servers.